# How to center a view on the x axis using autolayout in Swift on MacOS?

Tags: swift, macos, autolayout, nsview

Hi I'm just wanting to have a `childView` centered on the x axis of a `NSViewController` `view` using auto layout. I'm doing the following:

```
override func viewWillAppear()
{
    super.viewWillAppear()

    let childView = PagesView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:100, height: 100))
    childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(childView)

    childView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

The `childView` doesn't even appear on the screen. When I remove the last line, then it gets positioned at 0,0. So something about that last line is causing it go haywire and I'm not sure why? I've used this exact same logic on iOS and it has worked fine.

Comment: I’m wondering if `self.view` has a `centerXAnchor` attribute, did you set one in the storyboard, maybe try printing it.

Comment: @ParadoxProgramming Nah I was using whatever the default value was in the storyboard and I don't think it was set to anything. folverap answer below helped me solve it, I needed to set the top, width, and height anchors as well.

Comment: Glad it got fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All views should have constraints to define its location and size.

```
// This would create dimension constraints if your class cannot already infer them
childView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
childView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

You also need to specify a vertical anchor constraint so the view has enough information to be displayed.

```
childView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```